# Trying to use dd to write an iso to a usb stick to be used in Windows 7

Tags: iso, dd

I have a Win7/64 laptop without a DVD drive, and a copy of Office on a DVD I'd like to install.

I figured I could use another machine running Xubuntu 14.04 to make an ISO of the disk, write that ISO to a USB stick, and then install that on the first machine

My problem is this:  I use dd to write the ISO to the USB drive, and it looks like it took a good copy, but when I try to use it on the windows machine, I get a report that the USB stick's "Disk structure is corrupted and unreadable".

Some more information:

- I start with the usb drive formatted to NTFS.  The Windows Machine *can* read it at this point
- I'm using the following command:
  sudo dd bs=4M if=office.iso of=/dev/sdb
- I've tried the above with the ISO on both my Linux machine's HDD, and ripping straight from the CD.
- I've tried formatting the USB stick on both Linux (with gparted) and on Windows, both with no luck.

Am I using dd wrong?  Is there something else I should use?  At this point I can just download office onto that machine, but I'd like to figure this out for another time

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Your question is good, but it could be a bit better. Some tips: 1) put inline commands between two of these ` so it becomes like this: ``ls -al`` 2) try to change the title so it is a question, so it can end with a questionmark. Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.  Followed the instructions here on ServerFault for [creating a bootable windows USB drive in Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux)

I had ignored this until now, since I didn't think I needed a bootable USB drive.  But this method seemed to preserve the partition information on the USB drive in such a manner that Windows was able to read it.

The [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/167060/372359) is by [jthurner](https://serverfault.com/users/50170/jthurner)

> Install ms-sys - if it is not in your repositories, get it
>   [here](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/). Or alternatively, make sure lilo is installed (but **do
>   not** run the liloconfig step on your local box if e.g. Grub is
>   installed there!)
>
> Check what device your USB media is assigned - here we will assume it
>   is `/dev/sdb`. Delete all partitions, create a new one taking up all
>   the space, set type to NTFS (7), and remember to set it bootable:
>
> `sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb`   *or* `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`  (partition
>   **type 7**, and **bootable** flag)
>
> Create an NTFS filesystem:
>
> ```
> sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1`
> ```
>
> Write Windows 7 [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) on the USB stick (also works for windows 8),
>   multiple options here:
>
> 1. `sudo ms-sys -7 /dev/sdb`
> 2. or (e.g. on newer Ubuntu installs) `sudo lilo -M  /dev/sdb mbr` ([info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record))
> 3. or (if syslinux is installed), you can run `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdb`
>
> Mount ISO and USB media:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -o loop win7.iso /mnt/iso
> sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
> ```
>
> Copy over all files:
>
> ```
> sudo cp -r /mnt/iso/* /mnt/usb/
> ```
>
> (or use the standard GUI file-browser of your system)
>
> Call `sync` to make sure all files are written.

Comment: Please add the relevant part in the answer body.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make a linux usb pen with NTFS format.

Next time you can use http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

i created hundreds of linux pens with this program and never had a problem